# jQuery check if text is non-english

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I want check if text is non-english charachter , i wrote this code but unfortunately not working:

```
var objsts = $('a');
var english = /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/;

$.each(objsts, function () {
var $this = $(this);
if (!$this.html() == english)
$this.addClass('active');
});
```

any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since english is a regex use the `test()` method

```
if (!english.test($this.html()))
```